# WPF-Custom Popup Placement according to screen

Tags: wpf, xaml, popup, offset

I am New in WPF. In WPF application I have Listview. I am showing popup control for information on "Remark" cell below is image.
[image]

Poup is taking proper position on every toggle button click but in case I change the resoultion of my screen or run on someother screen it moves from its relative position.

What is the way to update horizontal and vertical offset of popup according to screen size, code snippet for popup is as follows

```
<Popup Name="PopupRemark" AllowsTransparency="True" Placement="Left" HorizontalOffset="48"  VerticalOffset="-22"
                                            PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ToggleButton}}" 
                                            IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=btnInfo}"  StaysOpen="False"  >
```

Is there any solution to update popup position according to screen

Comment: I refer this link :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39786296/wpf-popup-with-arrow-head-style and solved my issue